# Does the latest Facebook SDK automatically check if its app is installed? It says it will.... but its not happening for me

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I would like to provide the option to share a picture to Facebook.  When I have the FB app installed, I have no problem posting to my feed.  However, when no app is installed, I get the following error:

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"

Facebook says in the docs I don't need to do anything:

> Now the SDK automatically checks for the native Facebook app. If it isn't installed, the SDK switches people to their default browser and opens the Feed Dialog. If someone wants to share an Open Graph story, the SDK opens the Web Share Dialog.

One hack I found to check is the following:

```
BOOL isInstalled = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fbauth2:/"]];
 if (isInstalled) {....}
```

Is there a better more 'correct' way?

The method I use to share that throws the error is the following:

```
- (void)showFBShare {

FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
photo.image = self.shareImage;
photo.userGenerated = YES;
FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
content.photos = @[photo];

[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                             withContent:content
                                delegate:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: Instantiate and configure FBSDKShareDialog as dialog and set dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeNative or FBSDKShareDialogModeShareSheet. if [dialog canShow] then [dialog show].

> FBSDK version used for testing solution:
>   - FBSDKCoreKit (4.12.0):
>   - FBSDKShareKit (4.12.0):

It does not seem like the method throws any exceptions when calling the showFromViewController method so a try / catch fix is ruled out. However if you instantiate the FBSDKShareDialog you can call the canShow method to check if the app is able to show the dialog in its **current mode** (in this case FBSDKShareDialogModeShareSheet).

> ***Method description from source (FBSDKSharing.h:64):***
>
> @abstract A Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver can initiate a share.
>    @discussion May return NO if the appropriate Facebook app is not installed and is required or an access token is
>    required but not available.  This method does not validate the content on the receiver, so this can be checked before
>    building up the content.
>    @see [FBSDKSharing validateWithError:]
>    @result YES if the receiver can share, otherwise NO.
>   ***- (BOOL)canShow;***

Code example:

```
...

FBSDKShareDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
dialog.fromViewController = self;
dialog.shareContent = content;

/** 
 * !important: Only mode FBSDKShareDialogModeNative and
 * FBSDKShareDialogModeShareSheet do the appropriate checks. 
 * Otherwise canShow returns yes regardless. 
 */
dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeShareSheet; 

if ([dialog canShow]) {
    [dialog show];
} else {
    // handle exception case.
}
```

Issues when running on the simulator (from the docs):

> **iOS Simulator and Testing**
>
> If you are using Simulator to test sharing in your application, you will see errors if you try to share videos, Photos or Open Graph Actions. This is because you need Facebook for iOS installed which provides the Share Dialog. We do not support this for Simulator.
>
> In the case of link shares, you do not need Facebook for iOS installed so this test case is possible. To test other Sharing scenarios, set up an actual test device with with Facebook for iOS installed.

As mentioned above, only link content is supported on the simulator. I.e.:

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *linkContent = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
linkContent.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"somelink"];
linkContent.quote = @"Very interesting, shareworthy link.";

[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                         withContent:linkContent
                            delegate:nil];
```